# Login As Guest Best Practice for Mobile App

Tags: android, ios, authentication

I have seen many mobile apps these days that are using Guest as login. Are they using some types of hardware serial number to generate the Uid for this type of user?

If so, what comes up to my mind first is the mac-address, then, the IMEI.

I'm just not sure of which is best, and need recommendations for both platform iOS and Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Parse.com as the backend for my app.  This handles anonymous login for you if you need it